# Game Consecutive Input Check

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements

I have been working on a game of hangman and have finished up with nearly all of the heavy coding. However, I am having an issue with testing for consecutive input. I would like to close the program if the user has entered something other than "yes" or "no" *three times consecutively* when prompted if they would like to play hangman. I have only managed to come up with a way that closes the program if the user has entered three *total* error inputs. Below is my code. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyFuncts.h"
#include "randword.h"
using namespace std;

void drawHangman(int incorrectCount);
int askToPlay();
int response = 0;
int incorrectCount = 0;
void gameSequence();

int main()
{
string reply = " ";
int consecutiveErrors = 0;
getWords("hangman.dat");
do
{
    askToPlay();
    if (response == PLAY)
    {
        gameSequence();
    }
    else if (response == STOP)
    {
        cout << "Goodbye\n";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        consecutiveErrors++;
        cout << "ERROR\n";
    }
} while (getNextWord() != "" && consecutiveErrors < 3);
system("pause");
}

void drawHangman(int incorrectCount)
{
if (incorrectCount == 0)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 1)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 2)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    " |      |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 3)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|      |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 4)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|-     |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 5)
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|-     |\n"
    "/       |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
else
    cout << " -------|\n"
    " |      |\n"
    " O      |\n"
    "-|-     |\n"
    "/ \\     |\n"
    "        |\n"
    "      -----\n\n";
}

int askToPlay()
{
string reply = " ";
cout << "\nDo you want to play hangman? (y or n): ";
cin >> reply;
response = promptYN(reply);
return response;
}

void gameSequence()
{
string guessWord = " ";
char guessLetter = ' ';
cout << "Let's PLAY\n\n";
guessWord = strToUpper(getNextWord());
cout << "Word to Guess: " << guessWord << endl << endl;

while (incorrectCount < 6)
{
    drawHangman(incorrectCount);
    cout << "Enter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> guessLetter;
    guessLetter = toupper(guessLetter);
    cout << "You entered: " << guessLetter << endl << endl;
    if (guessWord.find(guessLetter) != string::npos)
        cout << guessLetter << " is in the word to guess.\n\n";
    else
    {
        cout << guessLetter << " is NOT in the word to guess.\n\n";
        incorrectCount++;
        if (incorrectCount == 6)
        {
            drawHangman(incorrectCount);
            cout << "Sorry you lose - the word was: " << guessWord << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
incorrectCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: have you considered setting `consecutiveErrors` to zero when you start a game, right before you call `gameSequence()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset `consecutiveErrors` to `0` whenever `response` equals `PLAY`.

The `if` statements in your `while` loop would resemble the following:

```
if (response == PLAY) {
    consecutiveErrors = 0; // add this line
    gameSequence();
} else if (response == STOP) {
    cout << "Goodbye\n";
    break;
} else {
    consecutiveErrors++;
    cout << "ERROR\n";
}
```

Comment: No problem @WallaceMogerty if this answered your question could you mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your main loop you increment the `consecutiveErrors` counter on every error, but you are not clearing it upon an acceptable response. Simply set `consecutiveErrors` to 0 when ever you get an acceptable response.